# What is the difference between $('#___') and $('.___') in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I often see these 2 selectors, what is the difference? Thanks

Comment: too many votes and comments for this!!!. You can get this in any book or googling for sure.

Comment: `$('.___')` is a sad whale. `$('#___')` is a beaten up whale.

Answer (score 9):

This is a ID selector (1)

```
$("#el")
```

This is a class selector (2)

```
$(".el")
```

So

```
<div id="el"></div> <-- (1) matches this -->
<div class="el"></div> <-- (2) matches this -->
```

References

- [All Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
- [Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 4):

`#` matches an element with that ID. `.` matches elements with that class.

See more: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

$("#id") selects element by its id, while $(".class") selects elements by the specified class.

Answer (score 1):

The # version is seeking by tag ID while the . version searches by CSS class.